# Redmine auth_token missing when editing comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-api

When try to edit comment i am getting this error

```
 422

 Invalid form authenticity token.
```

log/production.log says

```
  Rendered journals/_notes_form.html.erb (3.2ms)

  Rendered journals/edit.js.erb (3.6ms)

Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

Started POST "/journals/edit/178" for 39.32.17.135 at 2015-05-22 01:20:09 +0000

Processing by JournalsController#edit as HTML

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "notes"=>"mynotes", "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"178"}

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

  Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.2ms)

Filter chain halted as :verify_authenticity_token rendered or redirected

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 9ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: Do you have two or more instances in the same domain?

Comment: No, only one instance. I am able to do all other changes just can't edit the comments, Also no plugin was installed.

Comment: I run rake tmp:cache:clear and restared apache now i can't even logged in same error